# Can't display flex slider

Tags: jquery, wordpress, flexslider

This is my site: http://kairosblog.mx

I can't display the flexislider, however it does work locally. I'm using wordpress but things are getting pretty confusing.

here is the code but you can preferably check it directly at Kairosblog.mx:

```
 <div id="imageslider" class="container">
   <div class="flexslider loading" style="max-width:1170px; margin-left: auto; margin-right:auto;">
     <ul class="slides">
       <li> 
         <img src="wp-content/uploads/2014/11/slide1.jpg" alt="" />
       </li>
       <li> 
         <img src="wp-content/uploads/2014/11/DSC_0030-1170x400.jpg" alt="" />
       </li>
       <li> 
         <img src="wp-content/uploads/2014/11/DSC_0121-1170x400.jpg" alt="" />
       </li>
     </ul>
   </div> <!--Flex Slides-->
 </div><!--Container-->
```

```
          <script type="text/javascript">
            jQuery(window).load(function () {
              jQuery('.flexslider').flexslider({
                animation: "fade",
                animationSpeed: 500,
                slideshow: 1,
                slideshowSpeed: 7000,
                smoothHeight: true,

                before: function(slider) {
                  slider.removeClass('loading');
                }  
              });
            });
          </script>
```

Comment: When I looked at the debug console in Chrome, it is reporting an error on " jQuery('.flexslider').flexslider({" saying that it cannot find the function flexslider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have your flexslider script included on your website.

Comment: Wow didnt notice that, sorry im kinda new to wordpress thanks